# Coefficient of Determination and Correlation between observed and fitted value in Multiple Linear Regression.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, correlation, linear-regression

Consider Multiple Linear Model
$$y= X\beta + \epsilon$$
Then using Ordinary Least Square, we get estimate of $\beta$ as
$$\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$$
And $$\hat{y} = X\hat{\beta}$$
$$SS_{\rm Res}= (y-X\hat{\beta})'(y-X\hat{\beta})$$
$$R^2= 1-\frac{SS_{\rm Res}}{SS_{\rm Total}}  $$
From here how can we show
$$R^2 = (\operatorname{Correlation} ( y, \hat{y}))^2$$
This can be easily shown in Simple Linear Model as there is only One explanatory variable but I am not able to show this in Multiple Linear Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the residual $e$ is orthogonal (independent) to $\hat{y}$, moreover note that $y = \hat{y} + e$ and that $\operatorname{cov}(x,x) = \sigma^2_x$. Next, recall that $R^2$ is defined as
$$
R^2 = \frac{\sum( \hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2}{\sum( y_i - \bar{y})^2 } = \frac{
\sum( \hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2/n }{
\sum( y_i - \bar{y})^2/n }
 = \frac{ \hat{\sigma}^2_{ \hat{y} } }{\sigma^2_y},
$$
hence

\begin{align}
\rho ^ 2_{\hat{y}, y} &= \left( \frac{\operatorname{cov}(\hat{y},y)}{ \sigma_{\hat{y}} \sigma_y} \right) ^2\\
 &=
\left( \frac{\operatorname{cov}(\hat{y}, \hat{y}+e)}{\sigma_{\hat{y}} \sigma_y} \right)^2 \\ 
&=
\left( \frac{ \sigma_{\hat{y}} ^2 }{\sigma_{\hat{y}} \sigma_y} \right)^2\\
& = \frac{ \sigma^2_{\hat{y}}}{ \sigma^2_y}\\& = R^2.
\end{align}